# How can I convert a regular expression to work in a Bash script?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a Bash script wherewith I am attempting to extract the match of a regular expression and print it.

I have figured out from the Bash documentation that one can use the variable BASH_REMATCH to get the matched string and process it, but I haven't managed to convert a standard regular expression to a Bash-compatible one.

The regular expression is `\d+(?=%)`.  The string, wherefrom I extract the matching part, is

> Battery 0: Discharging, XX%, YY:YY:YY remaining

I wish to extract only XX, which is a percentage from 1 to 100.  My regular expression successfully does that outside of Bash, but inside of Bash it doesn't match anything.

Here is the script, simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash

acpi_out="$(/usr/bin/acpi)"
acpi_exp="\d+(?=%)"

if [[ $acpi_out =~ $acpi_exp ]]; then
  echo $BASH_REMATCH[1]
else
  echo "Failed to match."
fi
```

The output is always `Failed to match.` when it is expected to be `XX`.
I have checked that `$acpi_out` is indeed the correct string, but I don't understand why a match is not found therein.

Comment: Are you limited to bash _exclusively_ or can you use external tools such as `grep`?

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as a "standard regular expression" -- or rather, there is, but there's probably hundreds of different "standard"s for regex syntax, all slightly different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not understand `\d`, it needs `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`. And it does not support lookaheads.

If you are not limited to bash exclusively, but can still use other tools, my suggestion would be to use grep to extract the number from your input.

```
acpi_out="$(/usr/bin/acpi)"
percent=$(egrep -o '[0-9]+%' | egrep -o '^[0-9]+')

if [ -n "$percent" ]; then
  echo $percent
else
  echo "Failed to match."
fi
```

Now your script even runs in `sh` and not require `bash` anymore :)